# Can't commit to new private Github repository

Tags: git, github

After Github change private repository rules I have got some troubles.
Now all users can create/change own repository to private without Billing Plans.

I have Public repo and changed it to Private.
When repository is Public - I can push/pull via my git cli.

But when repository is Private - I can't push/pull via my git cli.

```
$ git clone git@github.com:myaccount/myrepo.git
cloning «myrepo»…
ERROR: Account `myaccount' is disabled. Please ask the owner to check their account.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

What's wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are making an existing public repo private, how many collaborators are there in your repo? there is a limit on how many collaborators there can be on a private repo without a billing plan.

From [github](https://help.github.com/articles/github-s-billing-plans/)

> In addition to the features available with GitHub Free, private
>   repositories on GitHub Pro include:
>
> - Unlimited collaborators

Comment: I'm only one collaborator.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, write about it to github support and they will unlock your account for a new free repositories.